# how to create a proc file for a discord bot in heroku?

Tags: heroku

So I have an application that would run a discord bot in Heroku, however, the files do not execute. I note that a proc file must be created. I do know it is just proc and not proc.txt, I do know it must be on the git repo on the root for, I just don't know what magical contents go inside. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [Hosting a Discord.js bot for free using Heroku](https://medium.com/@mason.spr/hosting-a-discord-js-bot-for-free-using-heroku-564c3da2d23f), if your app is based on Node.js, it looks like you need to put only one line of code there.

For Node:

```
worker: node name_of_bot_file.js
```

If your're using Python, the line is quite similar (more sophisticated answer available at [Stack Overflow: How do I host my discord.py bot on heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247301/how-do-i-host-my-discord-py-bot-on-heroku)):

```
worker: python name_of_bot_file.py
```

Comment: Aight, thanks!!

Comment: : holdup im using discord.py for this, do I just change the extension or...?

Comment: @CodeWritten it's quite similar, check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

how to do that for Java?
I can start my bot manually using:
sh target/bin/frdiscordbot

my Procfile is:
worker: sh target/bin/frdiscordbot

but I can't enable the dyno... the button is disabled and I can't enable it.

edit: to enable the button you need to click the pencil icon... very good site.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Rather than asking a question in an answer space, please ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). In your new question you can link to this question or its other answer for reference if you like. (Please note that this "answer" will most likely be deleted. *See information in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)*)